# Firebase auto generated UID changed?

Tags: firebase

I am using firebase for login and auth, and was using $createUser. For the first couple weeks working on my app the users I created were being generated with an UID like 'simplelogin:83'. Today, I am working on my app and users are being created with an UID that looks more like a GUID. Did something change on firebases' end? Can I control how that gets generated?

Comment: The format has indeed changed. For more information see: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/uid/firebase-talk/s9mv4S46Qs0/YPfpNz-VBgAJ

Comment: There is no way for you to control the format of the user ids for your app. If you're having trouble adapting your code to the new format, reach out to support@firebase.com.

Comment: Ok, no big deal, I thought it was something I did that made the change. Thanks again for your help Frank, much appreciated.

Comment: You're welcome. I wrote it up in a tiny answer, since others might have the same question and find this page before they find the Google Group.

Comment: If the format of the UID can potentially change at any point, what is the best way to link my users to data within the realtime database? For example, I currently have a user profile database with each user child being identified using their UID.

Comment: @PaulAlexander The UID format wouldn't change for existing users, so those ID's would be fine. When they changed the format, it was only for new users.

Comment: That's good to know, Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The format has indeed changed from `<provider>:<id>` into a single opaque UUID. For more information see [this post where the change was announced](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/firebase-talk/uid/firebase-talk/s9mv4S46Qs0/YPfpNz-VBgAJ).

There is no way for you to control the format of the user ids for your app. If you're having trouble adapting your code to the new format, reach out to support@firebase.com.